# Mustache not rendering objects on nodejs server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mustache

I have created a simple server (localhost:8080) to print the name of albums in a folder using Mustache, but it is not working.

**The way my setup functions is 

1. I run the server.js (written in nodejs) on the terminal 

2. localhost:8080/pages/home on the browser results in server.js parsing the request and calling in basic.html 

3. basic.html calls in home.js**

My home.js is:

```
$(function()
{
var tmpl, // main template - html
tdata= {}; // json data object feeding the template

// Initialise page
function show()
{
    // Load html template
    $.get("/templates/home.html", function(d)
    {
        tmpl= d; 
    });

    //Retrieve server data, then initialize the page
    $.getJSON("/albums.json", function(d)
    {   
        $.extend(tdata, d.data); 
    });


    // After completion of AJAX calls, parse the template 
    // replacing mustache tags with vars
    $(document).ajaxStop(function()
    {
        var finald= mine(tdata);
        var rendp= Mustache.render(tmpl, finald);
        $("body").text(rendp);
    });

}
show();
});

function mine(data)
{   
    if(data.albums && data.albums.length> 0)
    data.have_albums= true;
    else
    data.have_albums= false;

    return data;
}
```

The above (home.js) calls in home.html, which is:

```
<div id="alblis">


{{#have_albums}}    
<p> Number of albums: {{albums.length}}
</p>
{{/have_albums}}

<ul id="albums">
    {{#albums}}
        <li class="album">
            <a href=
"http://localhost:8080/albums/{{album_name}}"> {{album_name}} 
            </a>
        </li>
    {{/albums}}

    {{^albums}}
        <li> Sorry, no albums </li>
    {{/albums}}
</ul>
</div>
```

**So there is obviously a problem in the Mustache.render(.., ..) part of home.js**

After pressing enter on `http://localhost:8080/pages/home` in the browser, with the server.js running, I get the following in the terminal running server.js

```
incoming req.: (GET) /pages/home
incoming req.: (GET) /content/jquery.js
incoming req.: (GET) /content/mustache.js
incoming req.: (GET) /content/home.js
incoming req.: (GET) /templates/home.html
incoming req.: (GET) /albums.json
```

Side note: The result of running `curl localhost:8080/albums.json` on the terminal is 
`{"error":null,"data":{"albums":[{"album_name":"friends","title":"friends"},{"album_name":"travel","title":"travel"}]}}`

**I would like to see the album names in the browser on running: `http://localhost:8080/pages/home` 
 but that is not happening!!**

Answer (score 0):

I didnt have the file directories at the correct places in my system o_O !

The mine function (in home.js) is still not working - so I imported its contents into the main function.